# linq function for use with generic repository entity in where clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to use a generic repository to standardise some of my data access.
What I want is to be able to have a function defined in the interface representing the basic fields of my entity, so that I can use it to filter the results. This should be compilable into Linq-To-Sql.

e.g.

```
interface IEntity {
  Expression<func<bool>> FilterQuery(string filter)
}

partial class AnEntity : IEntity
{
  public string AName {get; set;}

  Expression<func<bool>> FilterQuery(string filter)
  {
    return AName.Contains(filter);
  }
}

class List<T> : where T : class, IEntity
{
  private IQueryable<T> items;
  public IQueryable<T>  show(string filter)
  {
    items = items.Where(AN => AN.FilterQuery(filter));
    return items;
  }
}
```

However, I typically get errors like:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to
>   delegate type
>   '`System.Func<T,int,bool>`' because
>   some of the return types in the block
>   are not implicitly convertible to the
>   delegate return type

What is the best way of achieving my goal, of having something generic defined on an entity which can be using in a linq to sql where clause?

Comment: This is a strange way to go about things... typically you wouldn't "filter" an entity, you would put a filter method either on your repository or possibly on strong-typed collections for your entities. I assume you want to do this to provide a way to say whether each entity in a collection matches some criteria, but you might as well put that logic outside your entity and have it operate *on* the entity, rather than *in* the entity.

Comment: Ah... Marc Gravell has pointed this out already.  I'd additionally point out that you'd need an *extremely* good reason to go about this... most persistence frameworks provide this type of mechanism and reimplementing it yourself as another layer of indirection would have to have a BIG payoff vs. the cost imho.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for all your comments. I can see that I was going about this the wrong way.
I guess what I want is a way for entities to flag up to the list method which fields participate in filtering, and for it to then filter on those fields. However, because it's all generic, the list method won't know the names of those fields (which will change between different entity types).

Comment: I guess http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx shows a partial solution, using a generic IValidFromTo interface, but it all depends on the names of the fields lining up from the actual underlying entity, which is really the problem here,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda for `Where` needs to take the entity type; I would expect that you would need:

```
interface IEntity<T> where T : class {
   Expression<Func<T, bool>> FilterQuery(string filter);
}

partial class AnEntity : IEntity<AnEntity>
{
  public string AName {get; set;}

  Expression<Func<AnEntity,bool>> IEntity<AnEntity>.FilterQuery(string filter)
  {
    return x => x.AName.Contains(filter);
  }
}
```

However; the `FilterQuery` method doesn't feel like an entity responsibility... (separation of concerns); which is why it isn't helpful in the "list" case; maybe you need to move that to the list? But when it works, something like:

```
T template = new T(); // this is a horrible way to get the filter!!!
                      // and illustrates that this method doesn't belong on
                      // this type; only done this way to fit the question's
                      // pretext - which I believe is... suboptimal.
var filterQuery = template.FilterQuery(filter);
items = items.Where(filterQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks Marc...
That's a good solution, but I see what you mean about 'suboptimal'... I'll add a comment to rephrase the question, see if there is a better way to achieve what I want.

Comment: I'm really just talking about roles; the method to filter *instances* of type A doesn't really sit well as an instance method of type A. It would work on the repository for the type, or as a *static* method on the type (but static methods can't participate in interfaces, of course).

Comment: Yes, I would have preferred a static method... but couldn't use one for the exact reason you describe.